# Why is past tense ("was") used in "It gets booked up quickly though so you’ d need to check it was available"?

Tags: tense, past-tense

> It gets booked up quickly though so you’d need to check it was available

Why is "was" used? I can’t understand why past tense is used here.

Comment: "If you wanted to go on a particular day" is implied.

Comment: You have a typo: if it was available.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [subjunctive mood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive#Use_of_the_present_subjunctive), which is sort of non-specific in English. It's not really past tense as much as it is referring to a conditional reality where one would like to book the room/house/travel in question. One way to rephrase it is as follows:

> (...) you would need to check if it were available [on the day you want to book it].

The use of *was* or *were* here is up to the speaker, though "were" is technically the correct form. I believe "was" would be more idiomatic in British English, while "were" feels more natural to my US tongue.